# Find the specific part of code used to draw a background line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to edit the Creative Common's released [Paradigm Shift HTML5 Template](https://html5up.net/paradigm-shift).

Basically, I'm trying to edit the color of these darker lines in the background.
[image: Darker lines in the background]

Yet I can't find the proper description in the css and, when I visualize it with Chrome Inspector, I can't find the related stylesheet part.
Is there a better method?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `#wrapper::before`. It has an inline background svg image defined in the `background-image` rule. See `main.css:3224`.